# Pass an array of ADODB parameters to function?

Tags: vba

I am attempting to create my ADODBcommand and parameters in the calligng code, so that I can pass them into a generic SQL function, but I get an error when retrieving the parameter from the list:

```
    Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim ParameterList(0) As Variant

    Value = Cells(3,3).Value

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@Field", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
    cmd.Parameters.Append prm
    cmd.Parameters("@Field").Value = Value    

    ParameterList(0) = prm

    Call SQLFunc(Data, SQLStr, adCmdStoredProc, cmd, ParameterList)
    .
    .

sub SQLFunc(ByRef Data as Variant, SQLStr as String, CommandType As ADODB.CommandTypeEnum, ByRef cmd As ADODB.Command, ParamList As Variant)

    .
    .
    .
    If cmd.CommandType <> adCmdStoredProc Then
        cmd.Execute
    Else

        'Append the parameters
        For i = LBound(ParamList, 1) To UBound(ParamList, 1)
            Dim TempParam As ADODB.Parameter
            Set TempParam = ParamList(i)
            cmd.Parameters.Append TempParam 'Error here
        Next

        Set Rst = cmd.Execute
```

Could anyone please advise how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After

```
ParameterList(0) = prm
```

`ParameterList(0)` is `Empty`, to resolve this;

```
set ParameterList(0) = prm
```

I would also strongly type this so instead of variant use `Dim ParameterList(0) As ADODB.Parameter`

The error you see occurs because you already append the parameter to the command before calling `SQLFunc`, in which you illegaly attempt to do so again. Parameter names must be unique when bound to a command.

You could remove the binding and use;

```
Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@Field", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
prm.Value = Value
```

Then `prm` remains independent of `cmd`.